# Running script in motion

Tags: motion

I have motion setup on a Raspberry Pi in rasbian-wheezy. Most of the `motion.conf` file works (I can view a live feed and it writes videos to the correct locations). However, I seem to be incapable of running anything from the `on_motion_detected` option.

Here's the original section:

```
#Command to be executed when a motion frame is detected (default: none)

; on_motion_detected value
```

and what I changed it too:

```
# Command to be executed when a motion frame is detected (default: none)

on_motion_detected /home/path/to/motionscr
```

`motionscr` is a script I wrote which works fine in a terminal using the exact same command. I also ran `chmod +x /home/path/to/motionscr` I can't find any documentation on the proper syntax for this option if I'm somehow writing it wrong.

I have already read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59091/problems-running-python-script-from-motion) and [this article](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2008/05/14/keep-tab-on-home-security-with-a-webcam-and-twitter.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have a script named upload_picture in one of my folders and I invoke this when a picture is ready to be saved. My etc/motion/motion.conf file has a line almost identical to yours. Mine reads:

on_picture_save /home/derek/webcam/upload_picture

my upload_picture script is quite simple. It sleeps 10 then uses wput to FTP the image to a web-site

I don't have an on_motion_detected setting, but looking [here](http://liamm.com/tech/emailing-or-tweeting-when-motion-is-detected-on-your-web-cam) It seems the format is the same for the two options. So I'd check that your script is actually being called. And I'd do that by including an **echo "Running" > /tmp/foo** line to the script. Also make sure whatever account is running motion has access to run the script, and probably that it has a shebang at the top (#!/bin/sh). When you change motion/conf you would probably want to restart motion and the link I copied explains that.

Another thing you could try is at the end of the on_motion_detected line put **>/tmp/motion.log 2>&1** which will record output from your script to a log file

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works for me:

`on_motion_detected /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/Scripts/MyScript.py`

Of course, the script must have the correct permissions to be executed by the motion process.  More details on the configuration can be found here:
http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigFileOptions

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me,  here is an extract of my /etc/motion/motion.config file

```
...
# Command to be executed when a movie file (.mpg|.avi) is closed. (default: none)
# To give the filename as an argument to a command append it with %f
#; on_movie_end value

 on_movie_end `/pass/to/your script.sh`

#
## Command to be executed when a camera can't be opened or if it is lost
# NOTE: There is situations when motion don't detect a lost camera!
...
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems this answer is not yet answered.

I have had the same issue and I suspect it could be because motion runs as the user motion and therefore does not have the necessary rights as the fileowner would.

Try
sudo -u  /home/path/to/motionscr

Comment: This would require that user `motion` have appropriate permissions in `/etc/sudoers`...

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
on_picture_save sh /home/path/to/motionscr.sh
```

Double check that:

- The 'motion' user is able to execute the 'motionscr.sh' script

  `sudo chown motion:motion /home/path/to/motionscr.sh`
- Whatever the script does, make sure all of their commands have the right privileges (user & location wise).

Answer (score -2):

Hahaha... I just found the solution.
Whenever an error makes no sense, then you know you've looked over something in plain sight.

Look at your command closely:

```
#Command to be executed when a motion frame is detected (default: none)
; on_motion_detected value
```

See the ';' at the 2nd line? The line is commented out...

Comment: The OP *has* removed the `;`, in the second example, where they have entered the path to their script.